# Building Lollipop 5.0 with minimal Embedded configuration

Tags: android, build, embedded, android-build

Does anybody know way for legal build Android Lollipop 5.0 with Embedded configuration? We used Jelly Bean before and built it with **BUILD_TINY_ANDROID** definition. Today this definition is obsolete. I found new definition **ANDROID_BUILD_EMBEDDED** but it also does not help. I found that with the latest Android build system we have some standardt products build configurations (build\target\product). I created the new device description. In my device description I tried to use build rules inherited from **embedded.mk**. But I have java errors and could not build the project. The same for base.mk rules. The minimum configuration I was success to build is core_tiny.mk. But I do not need JAVA and GUI all. Maybe somebody know how to define new minimal configuration which does not include JAVA and GUI for Embedded system?